# Layering of NSImageView above UIButtons

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, imageview, nsview

I have a layering problem with two existing buttons and a NSImageView. I have a custom view called PhotosView which inherits from NSView with two buttons (arrows):

```
@interface PhotosView : NSView

- (void)setPhoto:(NSURL *)path;

@end
```

In the implementation of the setPhoto method I add a photo to the PhotosView:

```
- (void)setPhoto:(NSURL *)path
{
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];

    imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[self frame]];
    [imageView setImage:[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path]];

    [self addSubview:imageView];
}
```

The imageView gets added on top of the two buttons. In my research I only found similar problems to iOS-development. The one helpful thread is here: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/55873-nsview-subviews-ordering.html, but I can't really believe there isn't an easier solution?

[image]

Comment: are you adding the buttons as subviews of imageView or as subview of self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your last line to:

```
[self addSubview:imageView positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:nil];
```

(See the API [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/addSubview%3apositioned%3arelativeTo%3a))